# ReactTable v7 - noDataText not showing on empty data (using useTableHook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table-v7

I am trying to display some data using the **react table v7**. It works perfectly using the **useTable hook**, except it just displays an empty table, without a **noDataText** as expected.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react'
import {
    useTable,
    useSortBy,
    useFilters,
    usePagination,
} from 'react-table'
import '../css/datatable.css'
import WarehouseAction from './WarehouseAction'
import { WarehouseContext } from '../context/WarehouseContext'
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext'
import AddStock from './AddStock'
import { Filter, DefaultColumnFilter } from './Filter'
import { InlineIcon } from '@iconify/react'
import ChevronCircleUp from '@iconify/icons-jam/chevron-circle-up'
import ChevronCircleDown from '@iconify/icons-jam/chevron-circle-down'






function WarehouseData() {

    const { warehouseData, getWarehouseRequest } = useContext(WarehouseContext)
    const { profile } = useContext(AuthContext)


    useEffect(() => {
        getWarehouseRequest()
    },[])


    
    const data = useMemo(() => [...warehouseData],[warehouseData])
    
    const columns = useMemo(() => [
        { Header: 'Stock', accessor: 'stock', disableSortBy: true, },
        { Header: 'Description', accessor: 'description', disableSortBy: true},
        { Header: 'Price', accessor: 'unit_price', disableFilters: true},
        { 
            Header: 'Total', accessor: 'units_total',
            Cell: ({cell}) => {
                if (cell.row.values.units_total === 0){
                    return <p style={{ color: '#f00'}}>Out of Stock</p>
                } else if (cell.row.values.units_total < 5){
                    return <p style={{ color: '#ffa600'}}>{cell.row.values.units_total}</p>
                } else {
                    return <p style={{ color: '#090'}}>{cell.row.values.units_total}</p>
                }
            },
            disableFilters: true,
        },
        { Header: 'Updated', accessor: 'record_updated', disableFilters: true},
        { 
            Header: 'Action', accessor: 'id',
            Cell: ({cell}) => (
                <WarehouseAction key={cell.row.values.id}
                    id={cell.row.values.id} 
                    stock={cell.row.values.stock} 
                    description={cell.row.values.description} 
                    price={cell.row.values.unit_price} 
                    total={cell.row.values.units_total} 
                    updated={cell.row.values.record_updated} 
                />
            ),
            disableSortBy: true,
            disableFilters: true,
        },
    ], [])


    const generateSortingIndicator = column => {
        return column.isSorted ? 
            (column.isSortedDesc) ?
                <InlineIcon className="inline-icon" icon={ChevronCircleDown} />
                : <InlineIcon className="inline-icon" icon={ChevronCircleUp} />
                : ""
    }


    const onChangeInSelect = event => {
        setPageSize(Number(event.target.value))
    }

    const onChangeInInput = event => {
        const page = event.target.value ? Number(event.target.value) -1 : 0
        gotoPage(page)
    }


    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        // rows,
        page,
        prepareRow,
        canPreviousPage,
        canNextPage,
        pageOptions,
        pageCount,
        gotoPage,
        nextPage,
        previousPage,
        setPageSize,
        state: { pageIndex, pageSize }
    } = useTable(
        { 
            columns, 
            data, 
            defaultColumn: { Filter: DefaultColumnFilter },
            initialState: { pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 5}
        },
            useFilters,
            useSortBy,
            usePagination,
        )


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="table-top">    
                { profile.is_admin && (<AddStock mode={"WAREHOUSE"}/> )}
            </div>
            <table {...getTableProps()}>
                <thead>
                    {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                                    <div {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                                        {column.render('Header')}
                                        {generateSortingIndicator(column)}
                                    </div>
                                    <Filter column={column} />
                                </th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </thead>

                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                    {page.map( row => {
                        prepareRow(row)
                        return(
                            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                    return (
                                        <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                                            {cell.render('Cell')}
                                        </td>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <ul id="pagination">
                <li className="page-item" onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
                    First
                </li>
                <li className="page-item" onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
                    {'<'}
                </li>
                <li className="page-count">
                    <strong>
                        {pageIndex + 1}
                    </strong>
                </li>
                <li className="page-item" onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
                    {'>'}
                </li>
                <li className="page-item" onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
                    Last
                </li>
                <li className="page-input">
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
                        min={1}
                        max={pageOptions.length}
                        onChange={onChangeInInput}
                        />
                </li>
                <select
                    value={pageSize}
                    className="page-select"
                    onChange={onChangeInSelect}>
                        <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                            Show {pageSize}
                        </option>
                </select>
            </ul>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default WarehouseData
```

[image]

Here is a visual of what the table looks like without data. How can I get reactTable (using usetable hook) to display a "no data" text when it's empty, and possibly a "loading" text when fetching data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `map` on `page` for each `row`.

So before that you could just check to see of page doesn't contain any rows, and return an appropriate message.

Eg:

```
{(
page.length > 0 && page.map( row => { ....... 

) || <span>no data....</span>}
```

Comment: I figured it would be going down this road. I was hoping the NoDataComponent or NoDataText as in previous versions would still be applicable. I forgot it's a headless library now. Thanks!